# belongs_to association without an extra table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a model `Download`, with a table `downloads`. `downloads` has a field called `ip_address`, which stores an ip address as an integer. I want to set up an `IpAddress` model, but without a ip_addresses table, so I can do stuff like

```
Download.find(1).ip_address.to_s # '127.0.0.1'
Download.find(1).ip_address.to_i # 2130706433
Download.find(1).ip_address.downloads # SELECT * FROM downloads WHERE ip_address='2130706433'
IpAddress.find(2130706433).downloads # SELECT * FROM downloads WHERE ip_address='2130706433'
```

I want it to behave like:

```
class Download < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :ip_address, :foreign_key => :ip_address
end

class IpAddress < ActiveRecord::Base
  set_primary_key :ip_address
  has_many :downloads, :foreign_key => :ip_address
end
```

but without having a useless table of ip addresses.

**Is this possible?**

**EDIT**

I found that ruby already has a [IPAddr class](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/ipaddr/rdoc/IPAddr.html).

So I did this:

```
require 'ipaddr'

class Download < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :ip, ...

  def ip
    @ip ||= IPAddr.new(read_attribute(:ip), Socket::AF_INET)
  end

  def ip=(addr)
    @ip = IPAddr.new(addr, Socket::AF_INET)
    write_attribute(:ip, @ip.to_i)
  end

  def self.for_ip(addr)
    where(:ip => IPAddr.new(addr, Socket::AF_INET).to_i)
  end

end
```

Then I can do lots of cool stuff

```
Download.new(:ip => '127.0.0.1').save
Download.for_ip('127.0.0.1').first.ip.to_i # 2130706433
```

Comment: This is possible, but it will get quite complicated to get it working exactly the way you want. I wonder if it's worth the trouble. muffinista's answer sounds like a good suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
IpAddress.find(2130706433).downloads # SELECT * FROM downloads WHERE ip_address='2130706433'
```

This is totally a semantics issue, but this should probably change if you have no IpAddress table (i.e. how can we find the IpAddress object 2130706433 in the database if there is no IpAddress table - unless you make IpAddress a container rather than a specific single ipaddress, otherwise do something like instantiate new ones with a constructer like `IpAddress(2130706433).downloads`).

Otherwise, though, I don't see any problems in not having the IpAddress table. Why do you need it to be `belongs_to`, rather than just another column?

You can keep the models/objects if you wish to access them in similar ways:

```
class Download < ActiveRecord::Base
  ##Whatever Download-model-specific code you have...
  def ip_address
    #If nil, initialize new object. Return object.
    @ip_address ||= IpAddress(ip_address_val)
  end
end

class IpAddress
  def initialize(address)
    @value = address
  end
  def downloads
    Download.where(:ip_address_val => self.value)
  end
end
```

**EDIT:** 
You can override the accessor, like you're asking. You just have to be careful in your code to be particular about what you're asking for.
See this doc: http://ar.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html
Under section "Overwriting default accessors"

Basically, if you do override the value, and if you wish to access the DB value, you use `read_attribute(attr_name)`, so the code might look like this:

```
class Download < ActiveRecord::Base
  ##Whatever Download-model-specific code you have...
  def ip_address
    #If nil, initialize new object. Return object.
    @ip_address ||= IpAddress(read_attribute(:ip_address))
  end
end

class IpAddress
  def initialize(address)
    @value = address
  end
  def downloads
    Download.where(:ip_address => self.value)
  end
end
```

Though things might get a little confusing in your code if you aren't careful.

Comment: "how can we find the IpAddress object 2130706433 in the database if there is no IpAddress table" By looking in the `downloads` table. See the HTML he wants that code to execute.

Comment: That's aside the point, though; the find part would be pointless to implement, the ipaddresses would be either instantiated with the number (`IpAddress(2130706433).downloads`) or otherwise stored in some way. It's a semantic difference, for sure, but putting `find` would seem to be out of context on a single object in this scenario (maybe if he was calling find on a container it would be different).

Comment: Is there a way to easily 'cast' the ip_address property of `Download` to an instance of `IpAddress`, then cast it back when the `Download` object is saved? Would after_create and before_save callbacks be good for this? And is there any danger of over-writing a property that is set by ActiveRecord?

Comment: You could name the column something slightly different (ip_address_val, for example) and make ip_address return `IpAddress(ip_address_val)`, would be one way.

Comment: Added example of how to actually override the value, as you asked. Be careful, though, as it might be a bit confusing if you ever call download.ip_address and expect the DB value instead of the object.

Answer (score 3):

`belongs_to` is really meant to specify an association between objects in two tables. But you're right, unless you need to store other associated data, storing IP addresses in a table is fairly useless.

However, you can use [scopes](http://asciicasts.com/episodes/215-advanced-queries-in-rails-3) to accomplish what you will want. You could have something like this in your Download model:

```
class Download < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :for_ip, lambda { |x| where(:ip_address => x) }
end
```

Then you would call

```
Download.for_ip(2130706433)
```

To get a list of downloads for that IP.

You could also add a class method instead:

```
class Download < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.for_ip(x)
    where(:ip_address => x)  
  end  
end
```

That might be handy if you want to convert from string to numeric IP addresses.

And, if you want an IPAddress class, you can add a method like this:

```
class IPAddress
  def initialize(ip)
    #presumably do some stuff here
    @ip = ip
  end

  def downloads
    Download.for_ip(@ip)
  end
end
```

Comment: I would like the `ip_address` property of `Download` instances to be an instance of `IpAddress` though.

Comment: You can always have an IpAddress class that isn't an ActiveRecord if you need it, and add methods to it to handle your lookup.

Comment: @CameronMartin, why do you want this? Do you *really* need it?

Comment: @Mischa An IpAddress class is a nice place to put integer <-> octet conversion logic, and maybe other IP address-related logic.

Comment: As I said to @DRobinson: Is there a way to easily 'cast' the ip_address property of `Download` to an instance of `IpAddress`, then cast it back when the `Download` object is saved? Would after_create and before_save callbacks be good for this? And is there any danger of over-writing a property that is set by ActiveRecord?

Comment: You could do something along the lines of what @DRobinson suggests, although at this point I have no idea what you're trying to do. This modelling is beyond excessive for what it appears you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: What would be the alternative? Having ip_as_int and ip_as_string methods in the `Download` model? Then what if I want to convert an ip address thats not stored in `downloads`? I can do IpAddress(2130706433).to_s if I have an `IpAddress` model.

Comment: If you need to look up both formats of addresses, then I would add logic for that to a method along the lines of 'Download.for_ip' above, or I would have logic somewhere else in the app to convert inputted addresses to a consistent format. I'm not convinced that you need anything more complicated than that.

Comment: If you really want to complicate things by making ip_address both the column name, and a reference to the object, it is possible. I've edited my answer to include how it would work, but I don't entirely recommend it because I feel that having the same name for both reasons could easily get confusing.

Comment: Using the hash notation `where(:ip_address => x)` is usually more concise than `where('ip_address=?', x)`.

Comment: I found out that ruby already has an IPAddr class which does much of what I want. So I just specified some getters and setters, and now download.ip is an IPAddr object, and can be assigned using any notation that IPAddr supports. When it gets saved to the backend, it gets converted to an integer automatically. See the update at the bottom of my post :)

Answer (score 0):

Add set_table_name "downloads" to your IpAddress and remove the relationship between the 2 coz it already has the column name ip_address.

This will give you queries in following way

```
Download.find(1).ip_address.to_s # '127.0.0.1'
Download.find(1).ip_address.to_i # 2130706433
IpAddress.find(Download.find(1).ip_address) # SELECT * FROM downloads WHERE ip_address='2130706433'
IpAddress.find(2130706433) # SELECT * FROM downloads WHERE ip_address='2130706433'
```